# when div is clicked change background

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I`m making sidebar, and I need to change background of the div.Now, when I hover it it shows me [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9c4o.png)

So this I need to do, when it is clicked, and of course, when I click at another div (for example "Search"), this background dissapears at "Home", and shows at "Search".

My code:

```html
                    <div className="navbar" id ="home">
                        <HomeIcon/><span>Home</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navbar" id="search">
                        <img src="img/search-navbar.svg" /><span>Search</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navbar" id="library">
                        <ListIcon/><span>Your Library</span>
                    </div>
```

```css
.navbar{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:white;
    opacity:1;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0.7;
    height:39px;
    width:91%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.navbar:hover{
  
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, .2);
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

Will be better if all code will be written on the css, but JS can also use.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch an active class using javascript though all your sidebar options like [in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/x0jskmqz/1/).
I'm including the code also

```
.box{
height:60px;
width:200px;
font-size:15px;
background:#ebebeb;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}

.active{
background:#f00;
}
```

```
var prev=document.querySelector(".box");
function active(e){
prev.classList.remove("active");
e.classList.add("active");
prev=e;
}
```

```
<div onclick="active(this)" class="box active">This is Div 1</div><br>
<div onclick="active(this)" class="box">This is Div 2</div><br>
<div onclick="active(this)" class="box">This is Div 3</div><br>
<div onclick="active(this)" class="box">This is Div 4</div><br>
<div onclick="active(this)" class="box">This is Div 5</div>
```